# How to I do add a function as a variable into a link url as a tweet for twitter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter, hyperlink

Ok so I made a random quote generator which works fine. I now want to take the randomly generated quote and make it a tweet. I know how to make text a tweet. My problem is taking the function that generates the random quote and adding to the url to tweet here is my code:

```
       <h1>Random Quote Generator</h1>
              <p>Star Wars Quotes</p>
               <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">New Quote</button>            <div class="row">
       <div class="quote-box col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
         <p class="quote">"Placeholder Quote"</p>
         <p class="author">Placheolder Author</p>
         <a onclick="getTweet();" href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.iconsplace.com/icons/preview/yellow/twitter-2-256.png" alt="twitter logo"> Use the Force to Tweet</a>
       </div><!--quote-box-->
    </div><!--row-->


    $(document).ready(function() { //random quote works fine
       function pickQuote() {
          var quotes = ["It's a trap!", "Mmm. Lost a planet, Master Obi-Wan has. How embarrassing.", "I find your lack of faith disturbing"];
          var author = ["-Admiral Akbar", "-Yoda", "-Darth Vader"];

          var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * quotes.length));

          var randomQuote = quotes[randomNum];

          var randomAuthor = author[randomNum];

        $(".quote").text(randomQuote);
        $(".author").text(randomAuthor);
      }

      $(".btn").on("click", function() {
         pickQuote();
      });

  //this is where the tweet magic is supposed to happen
  var a = pickQuote();
  function getTweet(){
      return "http://twitter.com/home/?status=" + a;
  }


});
```

Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
        var pickQuote = function () {
           var quotes = ["It's a trap!", "Mmm. Lost a planet, Master Obi-Wan has. How embarrassing.", "I find your lack of faith disturbing"];
           var author = ["-Admiral Akbar", "-Yoda", "-Darth Vader"];

           var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * quotes.length));

           var randomQuote = quotes[randomNum];

           var randomAuthor = author[randomNum];

           $(".quote").text(randomQuote);
           $(".author").text(randomAuthor);
           return randomQuote + " " + randomAuthor;
       }

       
       var getTweet = function () {
           var a = pickQuote();
           var url = "http://twitter.com/home/?status=" + a;
           console.log(url);
           return url;
       }
       
       $(document).ready(function() { 
          $(".btn").on("click", function () {
          pickQuote();
          });
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
       <div class="quote-box col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
         <p class="quote">Placeholder Quote </p>
         <p class="author">Placheolder Author </p>
         <a onclick="getTweet();" href="#" ><img src="http://www.iconsplace.com/icons/preview/yellow/twitter-2-256.png" alt="twitter logo"> Use the Force to Tweet</a>
       </div><!--quote-box-->
    </div><!--row-->
```

Comment: Thanks but maybe I should have added more of the html. the button(.btn) randomizes the quotes and is in the html before the html with the quote box check the html again at the top I added in the lines before that div so you can get the clear picture

Answer (score 0):

```css
.button {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #555555;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    /* Safari */

    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 30%;
    vertical-align: top;text-align: left;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: #555555;
    color: white;
}
#grid {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}
#gridli {
    width: 24%;
    margin-left: 0.5%;
    margin-right: 0.5%;
}
```

```html
   <head>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        </head>
      
        <body>
 

<ul id="grid">
   <li id="gridli">
      <form action="http://google.com">
         <button class="button" type="submit"  />
         Computers, printers, mobile phones and the widgets that accompany them account for the emission of about two per cent of the estimated total of emissions from human activity. And that is the same as the aviation industry&#8217;s contribution. 25 per cent of the emissions in question are generated by the manufacture of computers. The rest come from their use.
         </button>
      </form>
   </li>
   <li  id="gridli">
      <form action="http://google.com" style="float: left">
         <button class="button" type="submit"  />
         Computers can be used to reduce emissions produced by other industries, up to 7.8 billion tonnes by 2020, or five times ICT&#8217;s own footprint. Computers can make industries more efficient and less wasteful of power and fuel.
         </button>
      </form>
   </li>
   <li   id="gridli">
      <form action="http://google.com" style="float: left">
         <button class="button" type="submit"  />
         The use of computers has led to both positive and negative impacts on the climate change of our planet. Computers can help make some processes more efficient and save energy while the use and manufacture of computers contributes to the increased use of energy which leads to global warming. This website helps you to look at the positives and negatives of computing and climate change.</p>
         </button>
      </form>
   </li>
   <li   id="gridli">
      <form action="http://google.com" style="float: left">
         <button class="button" type="submit"  />
            <h3> Saving Energy</h3>
            There are many ways in which computers can help cut down on our use of energy. Computers are steadily improving the amount of energy that they use with the smaller computers producing less CO2 than larger desktop computers.
         </button>
      </form>
   </li>
</ul>
```